# Convert JSON to model in Laravel controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4, controller

Hi have this ajax call from jQuery:

```
$.ajax(
            {
               type:'POST',
               url:link.href + "/item",
               cache: false,
               data: { "loupe": loupe, "element": element, "loupeElements": loupeElements, "loupeAlias": loupeAlias, "elementAlias": elementAlias },
               success: function(data){
                    $(".carousel-content").animate({opacity:1}, 300);    
                    $(".carousel-content").html(data);
                    FB.XFBML.parse();
                    twttr.widgets.load()
                    return true;
               }
            }
         );
```

Which is passing data nicely to my controller:

```
class IndexController extends Controller {

public function getItem()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $loupe = $input['loupe'];
    $element = $input['element'];
    $loupeElements = $input['loupeElements'];
    $loupeAlias = $input['loupeAlias'];
    $elementAlias = $input['elementAlias'];

    return View::make('_partials.item', $input);
}
```

The problem is that the javascript variables loupe, element and loupeElements are comma separated json's ({"id":30,"alias":"mi-lupa","name":"Mi Lupa".....), so what I get in my getItem function in the controller is just a String containing that information. I want to convert that json to a model so I can play with it, however I am not able to find a way to do this in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

In your controller you can do something like this

```
$loupe = json_decode($input['loupe'])->id // this will give you the id 30 of loupe
```

Now that you had `loupe id` you can use `Loupe::find($loupe)` if you have a Loupe model

Hope this helps

Comment: you are so right... now I have another problem.... loupe comes escaped and it seems that is a problem. When I json_decode it what I get is null:  {&quot;id&quot;:30,&quot;alias&quot;:&quot;mi-lupa&quot;,

Comment: please show the exact and entire json string that you are dealing with

Comment: There you go master:   {&quot;id&quot;:30,&quot;alias&quot;:&quot;mi-lupa&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mi Lupa&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;La primera lupa que sirve para realizar pruebas. Caracteres raros: &#039;&#039;¡&#039;Ñ¨¿?!&quot;·ª!·&quot;//&quot;,&quot;creator&quot;:4,&quot;deleted&quot;:0,&quot;rtve_category_id&quot;:&quot;TE_SGOYA15&quot;,&quot;keywords&quot;:&quot;alfombra,roja&quot;}

Comment: thanks a lot for the data. Also set dataType: json in your ajax, please. While i figure this out

Comment: An update. I urldecoded the information in the controller, and now is alright. Still not being able to access the attributes in the view though. I guess I have to cast it to the model class.

Comment: Hi Dhiraj. Yes I did finally get it :D the problem was about special characters, commas and such that broke my json string so it couldn't be json_decoded. You guys helped me a lot already giving me direction about how to convert a string into a handy stdClass, using json_decode function.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do it in Laravel quite easily.
Lets say you get json string like

```
$jsonString = "{'id':'1','name':'ABC','age':'20'}";
```

First you can convert this in to a stdClass by calling [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

```
$rawUserData = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Then lets assume you have a Eloquent model called "`User`".
You can create an instance of the `User` class with above `$rawUserData` object's data as follows.

```
$userAbc = new User();
$userAbc->fill( get_object_vars($rawUserData) );
```

What [get_object_vars does](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) does is, it converts `$rowUserData` attributes in to an array.
So there you have it, User model with json data.

Note: You might want to check `$fillable` or `$guard` attributes in the eloquent model to filter which attributes you want to get filled with [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Hope this helps.